# MongoNetworkError when connecting from different container

Tags: mongodb

PHP dev new to NodeJS and I am struggling to get my NodeJS container to connect to my MongoDB container. As far I can see I have all the correct NPMs installed in my Docker file and the docker-compose is correct. Please note that I have not added the containers to the same network or but in the link to the db service into the nodejs container, although I did try this and got pretty much the same result.

Unsure why I am getting the error below when I bash into the nodejs container and run `node app.js`

**Error**

```
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
(node:92) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Server is listening on port 3000
Could not connect to the database. Exiting now... { MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED localhost:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at createConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:559:14)
    at connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:973:11)
    at makeConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at Socket.err (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:281:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:193:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5' # We use version 3.5 syntax
services: # Here we define our service(s)
  frontend:
    container_name: angular
    build: ./angular_app
    volumes:
      - ./angular_app:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    command: >
      bash -c "npm install && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200"
    depends_on:
      - api

  # NodeJS/Express service for API
  api:
    image: nodeexpress
    build:
      context: ./node_server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./node_server:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    links:
      - mongoservice
    depends_on:
      - mongoservice

  # Mongo database service
  mongoservice:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongocontainer
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${DB_MONGO_ROOTUSER}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_MONGO_ROOTPWD}
    ports:
      - ${DB_MONGO_EXTERNAL_PORT}:${DB_MONGO_INTERNAL_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ${DB_MONGO_VOLUME1}

volumes:
    data:
      external: true

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

**Dockerfile** (for api service - nodejs express)

```
FROM node:11-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
#RUN npm install mysql
RUN npm install mongodb --save
#RUN npm install --save body-parser express mysql2 sequelize helmet cors
RUN npm install --save body-parser express mongoose helmet cors
RUN npm install --save nocache
RUN npm install nodemon --save

EXPOSE 4300

#CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start.dev" ]
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create express app
const app = express();

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Configuring the database
const dbConfig = require('./config/database.config');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connecting to the database
// Connection string variants attempted
// mongodb://root:secret@0.0.0.0:27017/angapp2
// mongodb://root:secret@127.0.0.1:27017/angapp2
// mongodb://root:secret@mongoservice:27017/angapp2
mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:secret@localhost:27017/angapp2', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
}).then(() => {
  console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...', err);
  process.exit();
});

// define a simple route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({"message": "Welcome to EasyNotes application. Take notes quickly. Organize and keep track of all your notes."});
});

// Require Notes routes
require('./routes/note.routes.js')(app);

// listen for requests
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
});
```

**What I've tried**:

1. Attempted the various connection string variants in terms of the host name, i.e. localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0, mongoservice
2. Also ran `docker inspect <container-id>` on the mongo service and got the internal IP address of the container and tried that in the connection string
3. Added `RUN npm install mongodb --save` to node servers Dockerfile
4. Managed to connect Robo 3D GUI to the Mongo container without issue
5. Bashed into Mongo service and managed to log into the DB and run some statements as a test that the service was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its just me being blind but, it seems that you are trying to connect to your Database on Port 27017 but in your Docker-Compose File you set the Port of the Database to 8081. Try Matching the ports.

Comment: Sorry, I should have removed the mongo-express service as it was not been used. The `mongoservice` is the DB container my api was trying to connect to. Question updated